# how pass an array to plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, plugins

How can I pass an array of values from my script.js file to my plugin.js file and store it in a new variable?

plugin.js

```
var a=[]
```

script.js

```
b=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

How would I define a function in plugin.js that I can call from script.js and pass in my array of values?

here is a small piece of my plugin for you :

```
var firstChange="";
var q=[];
var a=['جعفر','13','true','بنز','رسولی'];
var b=['مسعود','56','true','بی ام و','صادقی'];
var c=['محمود','32','false','فورد','هاشمی'];
var d=['رضا','65','false','تزو','سروازاد'];
var e=['علی','2','true','لامبورگینی','مهدی خانی'];
var f=['صادق','55','false','کادیلاک','یاقوی'];
var g=['رضا','63','true','تورشه','مدرس'];
var name=['جعفر','مسعود','محمود','رضا','علی','صادق','رضا'];
var wealth=['13','56','32','65','2','55','63'];
var married=['true','true','false','false','true','false','true'];
var car=['بنز','بی ام و','فورد','تزو','لامبورگینی','کادیلاک','تورشه'];
var family=['رسولی','صادقی','هاشمی','سروازاد','مهدی خانی','یاقوی','مدرس'];
var same=[];
jQuery.writeTable = function () { 
    $("#name1").text(a[0]);
    $("#wealth1").text(a[1]);
    $("#Married1").text(a[2]);
    $("#car1").text(a[3]);
    $("#family1").text(a[4]);

    $("#name2").text(b[0]);
    $("#wealth2").text(b[1]);
    $("#Married2").text(b[2]);
    $("#car2").text(b[3]);
    $("#family2").text(b[4]);

    $("#name3").text(c[0]);
    $("#wealth3").text(c[1]);
    $("#Married3").text(c[2]);
    $("#car3").text(c[3]);
    $("#family3").text(c[4]);

    $("#name4").text(d[0]);
    $("#wealth4").text(d[1]);
    $("#Married4").text(d[2]);
    $("#car4").text(d[3]);
    $("#family4").text(d[4]);

    $("#name5").text(e[0]);
    $("#wealth5").text(e[1]);
    $("#Married5").text(e[2]);
    $("#car5").text(e[3]);
    $("#family5").text(e[4]);

    $("#name6").text(f[0]);
    $("#wealth6").text(f[1]);
    $("#Married6").text(f[2]);
    $("#car6").text(f[3]);
    $("#family6").text(f[4]);

    $("#name7").text(g[0]);
    $("#wealth7").text(g[1]);
    $("#Married7").text(g[2]);
    $("#car7").text(g[3]);
    $("#family7").text(g[4]);
}

jQuery.namesorter = function () { 
    var name2=name;
    var sn=$.searchname();
    name.sort();
    var a1=[],b1=[],c1=[],d1=[],e1=[],f1=[],g1=[];
    var a2=a,b2=b,c2=c,d2=d,e2=e,f2=f,g2=g;
    var same=$.searchname();
    var i=0;
    var temp=[];
    while(same[i]){
        temp[i]=name[same[i]];
        name[same[i]]="";
        i++;
    }
    if(a[0]==name[0]){
        a1=a;
    }
    else if(a[0]==name[1]){
        b1=a;
    }
    else if(a[0]==name[2]){
        c1=a;
    }
    else if(a[0]==name[3]){
        d1=a;
    }
    else if(a[0]==name[4]){
        e1=a;
    }
    else if(a[0]==name[5]){
        f1=a;
    }
    else if(a[0]==name[6]){
        g1=a;
    }

    if(b[0]==name[0]){
        a1=b;
    }
    else if(b[0]==name[1]){
        b1=b;
    }
    else if(b[0]==name[2]){
        c1=b;
    }
    else if(b[0]==name[3]){
        d1=b;
    }
    else if(b[0]==name[4]){
        e1=b;
    }
    else if(b[0]==name[5]){
        f1=b;
    }
    else if(b[0]==name[6]){
        g1=b;
    }

    if(c[0]==name[0]){
        a1=c;
    }
    else if(c[0]==name[1]){
        b1=c;
    }
    else if(c[0]==name[2]){
        c1=c;
    }
    else if(c[0]==name[3]){
        d1=c;
    }
    else if(c[0]==name[4]){
        e1=c;
    }
    else if(c[0]==name[5]){
        f1=c;
    }
    else if(c[0]==name[6]){
        g1=c;
    }

    if(d[0]==name[0]){
        a1=d;
    }
    else if(d[0]==name[1]){
        b1=d;
    }
    else if(d[0]==name[2]){
        c1=d;
    }
    else if(d[0]==name[3]){
        d1=d;
    }
    else if(d[0]==name[4]){
        e1=d;
    }
    else if(d[0]==name[5]){
        f1=d;
    }
    else if(d[0]==name[6]){
        g1=d;
    }

    if(e[0]==name[0]){
        a1=e;
    }
    else if(e[0]==name[1]){
        b1=e;
    }
    else if(e[0]==name[2]){
        c1=e;
    }
    else if(e[0]==name[3]){
        d1=e;
    }
    else if(e[0]==name[4]){
        e1=e;
    }
    else if(e[0]==name[5]){
        f1=e;
    }
    else if(e[0]==name[6]){
        g1=e;
    }

    if(f[0]==name[0]){
        a1=f;
    }
    else if(f[0]==name[1]){
        b1=f;
    }
    else if(f[0]==name[2]){
        c1=f;
    }
    else if(f[0]==name[3]){
        d1=f;
    }
    else if(f[0]==name[4]){
        e1=f;
    }
    else if(f[0]==name[5]){
        f1=f;
    }
    else if(f[0]==name[6]){
        g1=f;
    }

    if(g[0]==name[0]){
        a1=g;
    }
    else if(g[0]==name[1]){
        b1=g;
    }
    else if(g[0]==name[2]){
        c1=g;
    }
    else if(g[0]==name[3]){
        d1=g;
    }
    else if(g[0]==name[4]){
        e1=g;
    }
    else if(g[0]==name[5]){
        f1=g;
    }
    else if(g[0]==name[6]){
        g1=g;
    }

    i=0;
    while(same[i]){
        name[same[i]]=temp[i];
        i++;
    }
    i=0;

    a=a1;
    b=b1;
    c=c1;
    d=d1;
    e=e1;
    f=f1;
    g=g1;
    for(var i=0;name2[sn[i]];i++){
        var j=0;
        switch(sn[i]){
            case 3:
                switch(same[j]){
                    case 0:
                        a=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        b=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        c=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        d=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        e=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        f=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        g=d2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                }
                i++;
                break;
        }
    }

    for(var i=0;name2[sn[i]];i++){
        var j=1;
        switch(sn[i]){
            case 6:
                switch(same[j]){
                    case 0:
                        a=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        b=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        c=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        d=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        e=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        f=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        g=g2;
                        j++;
                        break;
                }
                i++;
                break;  
        }
    }
    $.writeTable();
}<!--namesorter-->
```

Comment: Please show us the code of your plugin. What you are asking is very simple! you can create you function like this: `function myFunction(myVar){}` and you can pass the array to your function like this: `myFunction(a);` But if you show us you plugin code, then this we may be able to help you more on how to pass the array as a parameter to the plugin...

Comment: @EhsanT dadash irani e shoma ? :D in func e ke gofti ke too plugin injuri tarif nemishe , man manzooram be sorat $.fn.func bud,

Comment: Dear @mowin-jj, Please try to write in English so everybody who browse your question can understand what's going on and can contribute. I'm aware of that and that's the reason I asked you to post your plugin code(a simple minified version) and then ask your question based on it.

Comment: @EhsanTthanks for reply , plugin added

Comment: 1- Why do not you use objects or multidimensional arrays for your data? right now your code is very messy! 2- so you want to send which one of your arrays to which function?

Comment: @EhsanT what do mean about object ? could u bring an example for me plz ? I wanna make an array with any values in my script.js and give it to plugin and my plugin overwrite that array into the for example "a" array in plugin. i wanna write this kind of func in plugin and call it from script.js but i cant.

Comment: OK, first, you can not pass variables as parameters to the functions by reference in JavaScript. But you can pass objects. Second, objects in JavaScript are like `var person = {name: 'جعفر', wealth: '13', married: 'true', car: 'بنز', family: 'رسولی'};` there are different ways to make objects which you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: About the function, if you want to create a plugins which will work on a `selector` then you can use this `$.fn.myFunction = function(person) {// your code here};` and then call it like this `$("#myDiv").myFunction(person);`. But if you want to create a function without a selector, you can use it like this: `$.myFunction = function(person){// your code here};` to call it, use: `$.myFunction(person);` you can use [this documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) for more reference

Comment: Also what I forgot to say was that you can access to properties of an object in the function like this: `$.myFunction = function(person){console.log(person.name)};`